# Windows 7 freezes on boot screen

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

There was some update that required me to restart my computer, so I did. when it restarted, it stays at the Windows boot screen forever, the screen that says "Starting Windows" and has that Windows logo in the middle.

I've tried the start up repair program that shows up when I click F8 when the computer starts. And tried system restore but, it says it has restored windows successfully but it still freezes on the boot screen when I reboot it.

When I try starting it in safe mode, it gets to the blue Windows background, the one with the logon screen, then says "Failure configuring Windows updates. Reverting Changes. Do not turn off." Then after a while it reboot by itself.

Just noticed, the logo animation on the boot screen is still animated. So it's not completely frozen.

EDIT: I waited about 3 hours and it still wouldn't get pass the boot screen. I'm going to have to reinstall Windows. =/

Comment: If the animation is there, let it sit at that screen, windows may be trying to recover.

Comment: i've let it sit for about 30 minutes now. going to try for a couple of hours next.

Answer (score 0):

Try running check disk from your install CD/DVD. 
http://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=6565

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: Did you try to do startup repair? : http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ss/windows-7-startup-repair.htm

Comment: i've tried that too

Comment: Than you will have to reinstall the system and just migrate your profile files back to your new user profile.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps, I experienced this problem today, my solution was to remove all other HDDs attached to the system excluding the primary OS drive.

- Unplug all other HDDs
- Remove any new / recently added hardware
- Put the problem OS drive into another PC and run scandisk / (other tools to check it's health)
- Disable Floppy Drive-support in BIOS